# How to: Group instances on Hair Particle system to shear and rotate

Tags: particles, coordinates, groups, hair, instances

How to make a particle System to instanciates objects and make them rotate on the z axis as well as bend in reaction to force fields like wind.

Using the "Render/Group" option in the PS properties, I get to rotate them ok but the particles do not bend with the wind, they lean to the side.

[image: Rotate ok but does not bend]

So I tried a different approach and added a Particle Instance Modifier to the object itself. This way the force fields bends the particles ok, But I couldn't make the randomly rotate the positioning.

[image: Bends ok but it does not rotate]

What is the best way to achieve what I want?

Here is the blend file:
[image]

Thanks!!!

TR